# create array of NPCs in a game

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am taking a Java class right now and we are supposed to be making a text based game.  One of the options in our game is to allow the person to choose between 3 ship types; small, medium, and large.  Based on their selection, they will be able to choose how many people travel on the ship.  Small allows up to 3, medium up to 6, and large up to 9.  Once they have made this selection, they are allowed to enter a name for each crew member and select a research specialization.  Previously, we had set these as separate menus (select Ship, crew size, research spec, and names) but I'm beginning to think it would be easier to select crew size, names, and research spec in the same menu.

That said, we are working on arrays/ArrayLists right now and we're supposed to use an array to list the characters (NPCs) in the game.  So, I need to figure out how to create an array based on how many crew members are chosen (between 1 and 9), have it then prompt for a name, and then allow them to choose from a list of research specs. They will enter a single letter for their choice but the array should put the full name of the research spec in it.  I found some code in another post I think might be helpful in this situation but it's barely scratching the surface I think. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public class Name {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<(how do I tell it to select a character option here?)> researchSpec = new ArrayList<(selected option)>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.err.println("Please enter the name of your crew member: ");
            name.add(sc.next());
            System.out.println("Please select a Science Specialization for your crew member");
            researchSpec.add(sc.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your crew members defined as their own class?  If you're simply storing their name.  Then both of your ArrayLists will use String as their generic type.  What you may want to do is control your loop to allow it to iterate and prompt you only as many times as it needs to.  The ArrayList doesn't have a concept of maximum size.  So you need to tell your program when it's time to stop adding new crew members.

Comment: The crew members are defined in their own class (characters).  The class stores their health, description, coordinates, name, and research spec. The problem I'm figuring out how to get the names and research specs of the characters (info added after the game starts) to sit in the character file with the rest of the info. As for controlling the loop for a set amount of characters, I'm not entirely sure how to do that if the amount of crew members can change based on user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a small, predefined set of possible values for something, an `enum` is often ideal for representing those.

```
public enum Specialization {
    PHYSICS,
    CHEMISTRY,
    BIOLOGY
}
```

Now, you can define variables of the type `Specialization` and lists of the type `List<Specialization>`, and refer to the values as `Specialization.PHYSICS` etc. This is better than using a `String` because you're not running the risk of e.g. misspelling a specialization somewhere in the code, such as adding `"Pysics"` to the list in one place and wondering why the `if (specialization.equals("Physics"))` never works.

However, you still need to have some `if`s, a `switch`, or a `Map` for the mapping from letters to specializations - unless you get fancy with the enums. An enum is actually a class, but you can't use `new` on it - instead, there's automatically one instance per identifier (in this case, `PHYSICS`, `CHEMISTRY`, and `BIOLOGY` are the three only instances). You can add fields, constructors, and methods to an enum class, so that you can endow each value with different properties:

```
public enum Specialization {
    PHYSICS('p', "Physics"),
    CHEMISTRY('c', "Chemistry"),
    BIOLOGY('b', "Biology");

    private char menuLetter;
    private String displayName;

    private Specialization(char menuLetter, String displayName) {
        this.menuLetter = menuLetter;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public char getMenuLetter() { return menuLetter; }

    public String getDisplayName() { return displayName; }
}
```

You can use `values()` to get a list of all of the values. For example, this will generate the menu options (I'll leave the selection as an exercise for you):

```
for (Specialization s : Specialization.values()) {
    System.out.println(s.getMenuLetter() + ": " + s.getDisplayName());
}
```

Edit: Or with a regular loop:

```
Specialization[] specializations = Specializations.values();
for (int i = 0; i < specializations.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(specializations[i].getMenuLetter() + ": " + specializations[i].getDisplayName());
}
```

Comment: Is this something I can include in the code above?  And how do I make a single letter select it from the enum?  Very new to the enum and array concept and I'm not sure everything is clicking with me yet.

Comment: Ah, you edited your post as I was posting my question back :).  Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: What does the colon mean between the for (Specialization s : Specialization.values())  ?  I try using that in the enum and it wants me to create a values class . . . also says illegal start type . . . so obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Hiattech: It's an [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with). If `Specialization` is properly defined as an enum, `Specialization.values()` will give you an array of the enum values, which you can loop over. What do you mean by "using that in the enum"? The loop was supposed to be in your `main()` method. Also, the enum must be in its own file; it's essentially a class definition.

Comment: I had posted my responded to you before I went back and saw that you updated your post.  I went through your updated post and was able to answer my own question.  I'm still having some slight issues getting the enhanced for loop to work but I'm still reading up on that.

Comment: @Hiattech: Great - however, the enhanced for loop is just a convenience (once you understand how it works), not a necessity. What you get out of `values()` is an ordinary array, so you can use an ordinary loop with it - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the update on the regular for loop. it helped figure out what I was trying to do and between that and some help from my team, we got it working . . . at which point NetBeans offered to convert it to the enhanced for loop. now I'm down to selecting the right option and, looking at Jufi's response, setting up the name selection to work with the specialization loop we just set.

Comment: @Hiattech: I saw that one coming :D - still, it's very good that you're trying to understand what's happening, rather than just copy-pasting code that gets you to the goal; this trait will make you a much better programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an Array based on the selection and then filling it would look like this:

```
NPC[] npcs;

if (amount > maximum) {// both values prompted
    System.our.println("Too much crew members.");
    return;
}

npcs = new NPC[amount];

for (int i = 0; i < npcs.length; i++) {
    String name = // prompt name
    Specialization s = // prompt that somehow -> enum solution by Aasmund Eldhuset
    npcs[i] = new NPC(name, s);
}
```

The NPC class would look like this:

```
public class NPC {
    public (final?) String name;
    public (final?) Specialization spc;

    public NPC(String name, Specialization s) {
        this.name = name;
        this.spc = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: not having a lot of luck with this.  'code' public class ChooseCrewNamesView  {
    
    Character[] Character;

    public Character[] getCharacter() {
        return Character;
    }

    public void setCharacter(Character[] Character) {
        this.Character = Character;
    }
    
    Character = new Character[ChooseCrewSizeView.crewSize]
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Character.length; i++) {
        String crewName = this.getName();
        ChooseCrewResearchSpecMenuView[] s = ChooseCrewResearchSpecMenuView.values();